# What Json response format to use for v2beta1 fulfillment webhook?

Tags: json, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have successfully tested my agent intents in the Dialogflow console where my fulfillment webhook gives responses such as:

```
{
  speech: 'You have 4 items, aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd ',
  displayText: 'You have 4 items, aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd ',
  data: {},
  contextOut: [],
  source: 'xxx:' 
}
```

Now I have set Dialogflow V2 API (v2beta1, I think).

I get a response:

> "Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Cannot find field: speech in message google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.WebhookResponse".

What JSON response structure/format do I need to use? The documentation on this is not at all clear. Can someone point me to the correct page - or describe it here.

If I do a search for "dialogflow v2beta1 fulfillment json response format", one entry seems to be promising: [Dialog Flow WebhookResponse](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/WebhookResponse)

But I cannot seem to find any reference to the field named "speech" (as per the error message).

Comment: Can you please share the full JSON you are sending from your webhook?

Comment: I had been using the json as indicated above - ie. { speech: 'You have 4 items, ...source: 'xxx' }. But I obviously need to change this. I am having difficulty finding the documentation - or a good example - that will include the field "speech" that the error message is referring to.

Answer (score 4):

It would be helpful to look at [the reference documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/WebhookResponse) for this API.

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": string,
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      object(Message)
    }
  ],
  "source": string,
  "payload": {
    object
  },
  "outputContexts": [
   {
      object(Context)
   }
  ],
  "followupEventInput": {
    object(EventInput)
  },
}
```

Instead of "speech", you probably are looking for `fulfillmentText`. It also seems like other fields in your response would not match either, so you should refer to the reference docs above to determine how to restructure your payload to match the required API.

Comment: As I indicated in the previous comment, I don't know that I can simply substitute 'fulfillmentText' for the 'speech' field - I cannot assume this. I am relying on the error message that specifically refers to the 'speech' field. This is what is confusing me. I would like to see an example of a raw json output that would be acceptable, but so far I have not found one. Google should really provide an example in their documentation.

Comment: You can look at this example project: https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-nodejs/

Comment: I changed my webhook response to use the field 'fulfillmentText' - as it does   in index.js - ie. let responseJson = {fulfillmentText: responseToUser}; (on https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js). But I get the same error message "Cannot find field: speech in message google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.WebhookResponse". As I am not using Firebase, it would be helpful to find an example of the raw Json that works for v2beta1.

Comment: It seems like your webhook is not updated or responding with some cached response.

Comment: The error message from dialogflow is really bad here. It's saying 'speech' field is not an expected field in the webhook response. But instead they are just showing the protobuf error message I think.

Answer (score 4):

Hi So I was facing a similar problem while trying to setup a webhook for my dialogueflow v2 beta . It took me hours of google search to understand the error. The error means that the field you have sent donot match the possible Message Fields you can pass inside fullfillment messages.

This is my cloud function that I m using for webhook and it works perfectly for v2. Follow the below link for the format of messages that can be part of the fulfillmentMessages array

[Message Format for fulfillmentMessages](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents#Message)

```
app.post('/v2/Hello',(req,res)=>{
let response = "This is a sample response from your webhook!";//Default response from the webhook to show it’s working
let responseObj={
     "fulfillmentText":response
    ,"fulfillmentMessages":[
        {
            "text": {
                "text": [
                    "Hello I m Responding to intent"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
    ,"source":""
}
return res.json(responseObj);});
```

The Below code works for v1

```
app.post('/Hello',(req,res)=>{

let response = 'This is a sample response from your webhook!' //Default response from the webhook to show it’s working

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //Requires application/json MIME type

return res.send(JSON.stringify({ "speech": response, "displayText": response}));});
```

This works perfectly for v1

Comment: Here is a better link for reference on possible formats in v2 and v1 from the original documentation: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide-fulfillment#webhook_responses

Answer (score 0):

Some things have changed for v2, and they're very particular about the format to return to dialogflow because they take it and insert it in the RAW API response json. I ran into this issue and found the template responses in the documentation [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide-fulfillment#webhook_responses) very useful.

Answer (score 0):

v1

```
var chat="success response";
  response.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
  response.send(JSON.stringify({"speech":chat,"displayText":chat}));
```

v2

```
var chat="success response";
  response.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
  response.send(JSON.stringify({"fulfillmentText":chat}));
```

speech---->fulfillmentText

displayText--->fulfillmentMessages

Dialog Flow Response has been changed from v1 to v2 
Please refer the Dialog flow documentation  for more details [click here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide-fulfillment#webhook_responses)

Comment: v3 would be `response.send(JSON.stringify({"prompt":{"firstSimple":{"speech":chat}}}));` using actions builder, see example response under [payloads](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks#payloads) for further details.