# Response dialogflow V2 JSON-PHP

Tags: php, json, webhooks, dialogflow-es

Probably this topic is a duplicate, but does anyone know why I get this error?

> "Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Cannot find field: displayText in message google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.WebhookResponse."

My webservice is a PHP file and I have an agent in V1 that works fine. But with the new format of response V2 I get this error.

This is my response:

```
{
    "fulfillmentText": "Este PQR no existe papi",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
        {
            "text": {
                "text": [
                    "Este PQR no existe papi"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "source": "webhook",
    "displayText": "Este PQR no existe papi"
}
```

Comment: Dunno but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211405/what-json-response-format-to-use-for-v2beta1-fulfillment-webhook

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check out your webhook JSON response. There's no field such as `displayText` mentioned in their JSON representation for v2 API reference. 
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/WebhookResponse

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": string,
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      object(Message)
    }
  ],
  "source": string,
  "payload": {
    object
  },
  "outputContexts": [
    {
      object(Context)
    }
  ],
  "followupEventInput": {
    object(EventInput)
  },
}
```

Comment: yes, thats the solution, thank you so much! for everyone, check the sintax and order of objects because that depend of API version. GRACIAS!